# Connecting Raspberry via ssh in a network

Tags: ssh, remote

I am using Dlink wifi router with ADSL broadband connection. My Laptop is connected by wifi and raspberry pi is connected via alan cable to its ethernet port. Now how do I ssh my pi?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=linux+ssh+tutorial See also: `man ssh` `man sshd` `man ssh_config` `man sshd_config`.

Answer (score 2):

I actually posted about this on my raspberry pi noob blog when I worked it out.

Plug the ethernet cable into your router instead and then follow the steps posted [here](http://noobsquared.blogspot.com.au/2012/10/shelling-in-from-windows.html).

My blog assumes you're shelling in from Windows but you can install these programs under Linux or MacOS as well.  Angry IP Scanner can be [downloaded](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ipscan/?source=dlp) from sourceforge.  Putty can too, or you can install it from the repositories.  Use "sudo apt-get install putty" under a debian based install (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint).

I think that's all the (too much) info you need.  Shout out if I've missed something.  Good-luck!

Comment: You should also be able to find the IP address by logging into the router admin panel; raspbian uses "raspberrypi" as the hostname by default.  The admin panel for Dlink when you are on its subnet is probably http://192.168.0.1/

Comment: Any reason you agreed, but didn't upvote me goldilocks?  I'm new, and was wondering if I missed something?

Comment: Nah I'm just jaded ;) Actually it's because I'm not a PuTTY user so could not verify the stuff in your link.  But it *seems* correct to me and you likewise seem on point +1